# Dropzone Js max File upload not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

**Notes :** i tired all questions & answer related this topic.

I use `Dropzone` js in my application. i want to restrict only 3 file Upload in my dropzone then work fine.

**issue is** i upload four Number file then my all previous three file remove. that is not correctly .

**i want to only alert in upload (four number  file). but previous first  three File not remove .**

**Steps:**

**1.** First three file Upload in dropzon.

**2.** Add one more File in Dropzone.  Then alert mess. only and **not Previous File Remove**

**My Code** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/mxxa0bk8/11/)

Comment: this.removeAllFiles(); remove this

Comment: thant is not working .. plz try to my jsfiddle . first upload three files and after upload four file then all previous three file remove .. that is not correct.. i want to only alert in upload (four number file). but previous first three File not remove .

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/mxxa0bk8/16/

```
 var accept = ".png";
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

// Dropzone class:
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone", { 
url: "/file/post",
 acceptedFiles: accept,
 uploadMultiple: false,
createImageThumbnails: false,
addRemoveLinks: true,
maxFiles: 3,
 maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
     alert("No moar files please!");
},init: function() {
       this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
this.removeFile(file);
});
this.on('error', function(file, errorMessage) {
  var mypreview = document.getElementsByClassName('dz-error');
  mypreview = mypreview[mypreview.length - 1];
  mypreview.classList.toggle('dz-error');
  mypreview.classList.toggle('dz-success');
});
 }

 });
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but i upload to 4 file then one file remove . and not alert mess. but i upload custom four file after three upload then alert mess display.

Comment: so you want message when 4th file removed ?

Comment: remove four file  i upload four file in one time then one file remove and not alert mess . but i upload three file and after upload four number file then alert mess display ..

Comment: so you want that if 4 file upload then non of them should be saved or 3 file should be saved and last one should be deleted ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will make your dropzone remove files when they are completed:

```
this.on("complete", function(file) {
  this.removeFile(file);
});
```

Add this right under:

```
this.on('error', function(file, errorMessage) {
  var mypreview = document.getElementsByClassName('dz-error');
  mypreview = mypreview[mypreview.length - 1];
  mypreview.classList.toggle('dz-error');
  mypreview.classList.toggle('dz-success');
});
```

Comment: thant is not working .. plz try to my jsfiddle . first upload three files and after upload four file then all previous three file remove .. that is not correct.. i want to only alert in upload (four number file). but previous first three File not remove .

Comment: Try again with my edits please and let me know of the results.

Comment: try to my jsfiddle .and save it . and send revise update Jsfiddle .because i can't understand what are you say.